# Play video on iPhone using OpenGL ES?

Tags: iphone, opengl-es

Can I play a video using OpenGL ES on iPhone? I dont want to use MPMoviePlayController class (because default controls also appears on the screen).

Thanks
Saurabh

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if you can play video with only OpenGL ES.
But you can change the control displays on MPMoviePlayController, to None, Embedded or Fullscreen.

Also if you just want your own simple controls(such as just playing and stopping) you could create your own buttons and send pause/play commands to the controller when their pressed.

Probably not exactly what you wanted to hear but its a decent alternative.